# Ice_cube gem and find method in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, find, ice-cube

I'm using Ice_cube gem to generate events, and looks fine. The model that implements the recurrency is called "Job"  , now I have a list of job, using pagination. I need to sort the Jobs in the list using the next events. The problem is that I'm using find method and will paginate to obtain the jobs . So my question is hoy I can sort the jobs , using the next event like parameter ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since the next event (or *occurrence* in **ice_cube** terminology) is not a stored field, you will have to sort them in your ruby code.

One way to do that would be:

```
sorted_jobs = Jobs.all.sort_by&:next_occurrence
```

Then use `sorted_jobs` as you wish.